# The probability of finding an electron of a certain energy in a rectangular infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The system of electrons in a box, i.e. in a rectangular infinite potential well, with length of 0.5 nm is described by the wave function $$\Psi = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}(2\psi_1 + \psi_2 - 3\psi_3 + 4\psi_4 - \psi_5 + \psi_6),$$ where the vectors $\psi_n$ are eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian for the system of particles in the box. If we measure the energy of the observed system, what is the probability that we will get an electron energy value of 13.54 eV?

---

Here is what I got so far: The energy for a particle in a box is given by $$E_n = \frac{n^2 h^2}{8m_\text{e}L^2}$$ and by plugging in $L = 0.5\,\text{nm}$ and $E = 13.54\,\text{eV}$ I got that $n = 3$. I don't know how to solve the problem further and how to use the wave function $\Psi$ with the calculated $n$. I assume that the probability in this case should be calculated as $|\Psi|^2$, right? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Apologies if the question is not appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if I have some wave function formed from a linear combination of the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian,
\begin{gather*}
\psi(x) = \sum_n c_n \psi_n(x) 
\end{gather*}
then the overall expectation value of the energy $\langle E \rangle$ will be given by,
\begin{align*}
\langle E \rangle &= \langle \psi | \hat{H} |\psi\rangle \\
&= \int_\mathcal{D} \left[\sum_n c_n \psi_n(x) \right]^* \hat{H} \left[\sum_n c_n \psi_n(x) \right] dx \\
&= \int_\mathcal{D} \left[\sum_n c_n \psi_n(x) \right]^* \left[\sum_n E_n c_n \psi_n(x) \right] dx \\
&= \Bigr \langle \sum_n c_n \psi_n \Bigr|\sum_n E_n c_n \psi_n \Bigr\rangle \\
\implies \langle E \rangle &= \sum_n |c_n|^2 E_n  
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{D}$ is the domain relevant to the problem of interest. This suggests that the squares of the coefficients give the statistical contributions to the overall average energy of the state. But to your question, the probability that you actually sample any particular eigenstate of the Hamiltonian when you perform a measurement is given by the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule). For linear combinations of the form given, this means that the square modulus of the coefficient associated with a particular eigenstate is the probability that you will sample that eigenstate. Since you are looking at sampling $\psi_3$, your probability is just $|c_3|^2 = \frac{3^2}{4^2(2)} \approx 28\%$. The Born rule is perhaps the most bizarre part of quantum mechanics, leading to the infamous [measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem), but deeper analysis of this is not needed to to answer your problem.

Comment: Complete solutions to homework-like questions are strongly discouraged on this site.

Comment: I understand. I was just trying to give a conceptual explanation of what the OP was confused about.